# Android - getSupportFragmentManager returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am trying to get a specific instance of a fragment using it's tag, but I am using a viewpager, which makes things difficult. I used:

```
public Fragment getFragmentByPosition(int pos) {
    String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + pos;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    return fragment;
}
```

to find the fragment, but getSupportFragmentManager is returning null.

the above method is in the activity, outside of the viewpager adapter class, and I am so lost as to what to do here. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you using Fragment or support Fragment ?

Comment: please post your full activity class

Comment: I'm using support fragment from the v4 support library

Comment: And I unfortunately cannot post the full class because I'm actually not allowed to.

Comment: Well I want to see where you use that method. FragmentManager has close relation with Activity's life cycle, that's why. And since you make it public, there is a chance you use it somewhere when you activity dead

Comment: I'm using it within the activity, and while the fragments are still on screen, so they can't have been killed off yet. I think?

Comment: I posted a slightly modified version of my class here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319456/android-getsupportfragmentmanager-returning-null

Answer (score 0):

You can use SmartViewPager from here
https://gist.github.com/jacek-marchwicki/d6320ba9a910c514424d

Extend your view pager from this class and get the fragment using getActiveFragment method. You can also change the implementation of this method to get your fragment by TAG name.

```
public Fragment getActiveFragment(String name) {
    final Fragment fragmentByTag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragmentByTag == null) {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        fragmentManager.dump("", null, new PrintWriter(outputStream, true), null);
        final String s = new String(outputStream.toByteArray(), Charsets.UTF_8);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find fragment via hacky way.\n" +
                "We were looking for name: " + name + "\n" +
                "Fragment with this name does not exists, or hack stopped working.\n" +
                "Current fragment manager dump is: " + s);
    }
    return fragmentByTag;
}
```

Comment: See the problem is that I'm not even able to get the fragmentmanager, so this wouldn't work. I still need to give it the fragmentmanager here, and since getSupportFragmentManager() isn't working, this wouldn't either...