# Android - getSupportFragmentManager() returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentmanager

I know there are a lot of similar questions here, but none of them have worked for me so far, so I'm hoping by just posting my (slightly redacted) class here, someone can help me out. It's a ViewPager using 4 fragments as the pages.

So my problem is that the method getFragmentByPosition isn't working, because getSupportFragmentManager() is returning null. Up in my onCreate, mSectionsPagerAdapter is also returning null if I try to call anything from that, however my tabs all show up fine, and I'm just not able to access the data from my fragments that I need.

I really don't know what the issue is at this point, so any help is appreciated. I posted a few other questions before, and tried the suggestions to no avail, so now I'm just posting up my entire class. Thanks!

```
package com.me.testapp;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.me.testapp.CheckListFragments.Thing1Fragment;
import com.me.testapp.CheckListFragments.Thing2Fragment;
import com.me.testapp.CheckListFragments.Thing3Fragment;
import com.me.testapp.CheckListFragments.Thing4Fragment;
import com.me.testapp.Data.ClientDAO;

import io.karim.MaterialTabs;


public class CheckList extends AppCompatActivity
        implements Thing1Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Thing2Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Thing3Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Thing4Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */

    public SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    public ViewPager pager;
    private ClientDAO clientDAO;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TextView toolbarName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_name);
        TextView toolbarFloor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_floor);
        TextView toolbarOffice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_office);

        toolbarName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Name"));
        toolbarRoom.setText(": " + getIntent().getStringExtra("Office"));

        toolbarFloor.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        MaterialTabs tabs = (MaterialTabs) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        clientDAO = new ClientDAO(getApplicationContext());

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_checklist, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    Thing1Fragment thing1 = new Thing1Fragment();
                    return thing1;
                case 1:
                    Thing2Fragment thing2 = new Thing2Fragment();
                    return thing2;
                case 2:
                    Thing3Fragment thing3 = new Thing3Fragment();
                    return thing3;
                case 3:
                    Thing4Fragment thing4 = new Thing4Fragment();
                    return thing4;
                default:
                    thing1 = new Thing1Fragment();
                    return thing1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        //you can leave it empty
    }

    public int booleanToInt(boolean bool) {
        return bool ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public Fragment getFragmentByPosition(int pos) {
        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + pos;
        return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }

    public int getCheckboxState(int id, String page) {

        switch (page) {
            case "thing1":
                return booleanToInt(((CheckBox) getFragmentByPosition(0).getView().findViewById(id)).isChecked());
            case "thing2":
                return booleanToInt(((CheckBox) getFragmentByPosition(1).getView().findViewById(id)).isChecked());
            case "thing3":
                return booleanToInt(((CheckBox) getFragmentByPosition(2).getView().findViewById(id)).isChecked());
            case "thing4":
                return booleanToInt(((CheckBox) getFragmentByPosition(3).getView().findViewById(id)).isChecked());
            default:
                return booleanToInt(((CheckBox) getFragmentByPosition(0).getView().findViewById(id)).isChecked());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add the stack trace when you meet the error

Comment: is really getSupportFragmentManager() returning null, or just the call to findFragmentByTag(...)?

Comment: It's definitely getSupportFragmentManager(), I tried separating that out to do further debugging and that's where it was returning null

Comment: And by separate I mean using FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager() and then calling fm.findFragmentByTag(tag) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

What I deduce it about the lifecycle of the activity, in the method onCreate the activity isn't totally created so when you try to pass `getSupportFragmentManager` its `null`.

What I do to resolve it, is putting this lines of code in `onStart`. The problem there is that each time the activity is paused and run it again the `Fragment` will be restarting.